# Is the center of the group with GAP id [48,28] trivial?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The group of order 48 with GAP id [48,28] is denoted by $SL(2,3) \rightarrow  G \rightarrow C_2$. Is the center of this group trivial?

Comment: Is that how you meant the typeset to look?

Comment: check if I will not modify meaning of ques.

Comment: Why don't you ask GAP?!

Answer (score 1):

$\operatorname{SL}(2,3)$ has a centre $Z$ of order $2$, and of course this centre is a characteristic subgroup of $\operatorname{SL}(2,3)$, which is (isomorphic to) a normal subgroup of $G$.

So no matter what the extension of $\operatorname{SL}(2,3)$ by $C_{2}$ is, $Z$ will be normal in $G$, and as a normal subgroup of order $2$, it will be central in $G$ as well.